# CSS negative margin incorrect when using box-sizing: border-box

Tags: css

When setting a negative margin to pull a child element to the boundary of the parent element which has padding, the distance moved isn't correct.

Here's a test case:

```
<div class='full'>
  full
  <div class='child'>
    child
  </div>
</div>

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.full {
  width:80%;
  padding-left: 3%;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
}
.child {
  margin-left: -3.75%;  /* 3 / 80 * 100 */
  padding-left: 3.75%;
  background: #ddd;
  color: #000;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/fuaxE

If I remove the box-sizing the margin is correct, but with border-box set the negative margin is correct - see the line down the left side of the child element.

Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is you have a miss calculation:

```
margin-left: -3.75%;  /* 3 / 80 * 100 */
```

It must be:

```
margin-left: -3.8961%;  /* 3 / 77 * 100 */
```

Because the real `Width` of his parent is `80%` - `3%` of `padding:left`. Check this **[Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/tyFBg)**

Comment: Note that this applies to both margin and padding of the child element because their percentages are calculated the same way.

Comment: Yep @BoltClock'saUnicorn you're right I just clarify this property ... i think the other one is implicit